# LaTex size is bigger in HTML spoiler

Tags: html, css, latex, mathjax

I've typed my LaTex code in spoiler, but the size is difference. Although their `font-size` are same but it's bigger than normal context. Here is an example.

```
<span style="font-size: 11pt;">$\alpha\beta\gamma\delta$</span>
<a id="ex1" onclick="document.getElementById('exx1').style.display=''; document.getElementById('ex1').style.display='none';" class="link">[Show]</a>
<span id="exx1" style="display: none">
<a onclick="document.getElementById('exx1').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('ex1').style.display='';" class="link">[Hide]</a><br>
<span style="font-size: 11pt;">$\alpha\beta\gamma\delta$</span>
</span>
```

How do I fix this?

The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VRQ8L/).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). This will help narrow down your problem. Your question is slightly off-topic now. See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Palec I have a problem in web design which also a programming problem. And I added the fiddle.

Comment: The fiddle is not valid HTML, but this should not be a problem in this case. It works for me as I would expect in Firefox 17.0.11 ESR on Linux. Both spans look exactly the same. Which browser do you use?

Comment: Chrome and I don't know what you mean about "the fiddle is not valid HTML". The result in the fiddle looks fine. Click [Show] and compare those sizes.

Comment: Your question still violates the 2) of the list of off-topic categories. Now invalid code, before including the fiddle even not self-contained. By valid code I mean code that follows the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/). You can verify validity of your code using [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: As I said, the fiddle shows me the first four letters of greek alphabet twice, all the same size, after clicking `[Show]`.

Comment: The size is definitely different. Check [this](http://s24.postimg.org/lgi02gfpd/K_20131202_376772.png?noCache=1385947722).

Comment: When I highlight the letters, I can see the size difference too now. It is very little, but still. The code produced by MathJax contains `font-size: 126%` for the first formula and `font-size: 130%` for the second one. I’ll look into it.

Comment: @Palec Thanks. Although the size difference is very little, it overwraps the texts right next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MathJax generates different HTML & CSS markup for the two formulas. The first one has `font-size: 126%` while the second one has `font-size: 130%`.

The problem is in the [HTML-CSS output processor](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/HTML-CSS.html), specifically in its `matchFontHeight` option. When set to false, both formulas have the same `font-size`. See http://jsfiddle.net/C6tyz/3/.

The interesting thing is that the formulas are assigned different `font-size` only when initially the first one is shown and the second one is hidden. I assume that MathJax generates the second one just before it is displayed for the first time and therefore the calculated `font-size` is influenced by the first formula, which is already displayed.

No workaround leaving `matchFontHeight: true` comes to my mind.

Comment: In response to the suggestion that the size of the first equation is affecting the size of the second, that is not correct.  Both equations are typeset when the page is first loaded, and before either is displayed.  The issue is the `display:none` CSS, as described in my answer.

Comment: @DavideCervone I did not have that much insight into MathJax. In fact I’ve met it (knowingly) for the first time. I just discovered the `matchFontHeight` option is to be blamed and guessed that there could be an error in the calculation. Now I know the problem is due to having to use fallback. Your answer is definitely much better than mine, +1. Thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 2):

The problem, here, is the `display: none` setting for the `exx1` element.  Elements that are `display: none` aren't laid out by the browser, and their sizes (like (`offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth`) aren't available, so MathJax can't determine the size of the surrounding font, or measure any of the elements that it needs to in order to typeset the mathematics.  In order to handle math that is in a container that is `display: none`, it temporarily typesets it in the `<body>` and then moves the result to the original location.  That means that the font matching is done to the main body font, not the font at the location.  That is probably the source of the issue here.  The difference between browsers may have to do with the difference in default fonts in use for the body element.

I recommend that you not use `display: none` if the contents contains mathematics.  There are several other techniques that can be employed to get similar results, mostly involving use of `visibility: hidden` and setting the height to 0.  See the [examples](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/talks/2013-01-12.jmm/examples.html) from my talk at the January 2013 JMM (in particular the one on `display:none`).